# Use $push and $max in aggregate

Tags: mongodb

Why I can't use $push and $max in the same operation during aggregate??

```
...aggregate...
   {
    $group: {_id:"$id",
    op:{
        $push:{"max":{$max:"$values"}}
            }
    }
    ...
```

.

"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$max'",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **$max** is a **group operator**, it must follow below syntax:

```
field:{<group operator>:<expression>}
```

**Expression** can't include **group operator** such as $push, $max, $min, ...

Comment: i'm trying to use $push and $ max in $group

Comment: I can't use $push and $max in the same "object" ? because $push haven't $max operator?

Comment: No, you can't do that as your question. You can group 2 times to achieve your intent.